# How to activate markdown on simple hosting?

Tags: hosting, markdown

Is it possible to somehow upload an .md file or such, written in Markdown to simple hosting ftp and make it work?

To show titles, headings, bold and such in a browser as if it's html document?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will need to convert the Markdown to HTML yourself first.

There are a number of different tools which can help you do that. For example, a [static site generator](https://www.staticgen.com/) ([more here](https://staticsitegenerators.net/)). There are some services which include such a tool as part of there service. You upload your Markdown and they use automation scripts to run it through a static site generator (GitHub Pages is a popular example which uses Jekyll under the hood). But those are not "simple" hosts. For simple hosts, you need to do the conversion yourself before uploading.

It is important to note that Markdown does not (usually) output a complete HTML document, but only a document fragment. There is no parent `<html>` tag and no `<head>` or `<body>` sections. The output of the HTML needs to be inserted into the `<body>` tag of some template. This is beyond Markdown's intended purpose and left to the user to work out. Static site generators serve that purpose. They include a templating system and configuration options to give you more control over how your pages look.

If however, you want simple unstyled HTML, some extended Markdown parsers include the added (optional) ability to wrap the output in a complete (but very minimal) HTML document. Pandoc comes to mind, but there may be others.

Finally, you could create a "single page app" with JavaScript and load Markdown files directly from the server and convert them in the browser using a JavaScript Markdown library. However, this would require a sophisticated landing page for your site. As all the work is done client side (in the browser) it does avoid needing to run a script before uploading and any simple server would work. However, if you are not careful, different browsers might give your users different results.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I meant how could I make my hosting to show me Markup syntax properly, not to ignore it? As if I wrote - # Hello - uploaded the file to the hosting, and then through browser I could see heading - Hello.

Comment: Yes, you need to covert your Markdown to HTML.

Comment: Right, but is there a way I could install some kind of script, or put a JavaScript inside my PHP document, so the included inside that PHP document Markdown file would be automatically formatted as a HTML?
Or just when simply heading to Markdown file located onto hosting through a browser so that Markdown file would be shown formatted as a HTML?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then you need the last paragraph of my answer. Although, I don't know what PHP has to do with that. I wouldn't consider a server which runs PHP a "simple server". If you have a server which runs PHP, then you can write some PHP code which converts the Markdown to HTML, but that would be a different question.